# How can I select date from SQL Server to TextBox in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to query date value and show it in a textbox in html but it does not work.

Maybe I am missing something? Can someone please help?

Type in SQL Server

```
2015/5/4   yyyy/mm/dd
```

and in C#

```
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    this.E_date.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[0]["EX_Date"]).ToString("yyyy/dd/mm");
}
```

ASPX markup:

```
<input id="E_date" type="date"  runat="server" />
```

Thank for answer

Comment: What do you mean by _not work_? You get any exception or error message? What is the type and value of `dt.Rows[0]["EX_Date"]`? What is your `CurrentCulture`? Can you please be more specific about your problem? `mm` specifier is for minutes, `MM` specifier is for months by the way.

Comment: You have set the type to date.  If your date format does not match what the browser is expecting, it will not display anything.  Try setting the type to text and see if the date shows up.  If so, then you know the problem is related to your browsers date setting.

Comment: please include try catch block so that you can find error..

Comment: No aliert Error data just no show in TEXT box

Comment: @SonerGönül EX_DATE  = columm in sql server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try specifying CultureInfo.InvariantCulture:

Example

```
string text = dateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff",
                            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[0]["EX_Date"]).ToString("yyyy/dd/mm HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Comment: check your database column EX_Date and values in the row. Are the rows empty or any data present?. If present how is it present in dd/mm/yyyy format or any other format?. How did you declare the data type in  column EX_Date?

Comment: value in database columm EX_DATE  is 2015-05-04

Comment: value in data base is 2015-05-04

Comment: I think you are using incorrect column name. Your column name in db is EX_DATE  but in your code you are using as EX_Date. Try using the exact column name as in db. (dt.Rows[0]["EX_DATE"]).

Comment: Did you solve this issue?.  If the answer provided by stack overflow members is useful to you, please do not forget to up vote and accept the answer. You can also down vote if you think that answer is wrong or not useful.